# Python Web Scraping Product Price

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to web scrape the product price on this site: https://www.webhallen.com/se/product/232445-Logitech-C920-HD-Pro-Webcam

I tried using

```
price = str(soup.find('div', {"class": "add-product-to-cart"}))
```

and

```
price = soup.find(id="add-product-to-cart").get_text()
```

But unfortunately, I had no luck. The item returns no price. The price/text is stored in a span class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire website is behind `JavaScript` so you won't fetch anything with `bs4`. However, there's an API endpoint with all the data you need.

Here's how to get it:

```py
import requests

with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get("https://www.webhallen.com/api/product/232445").json()
    print(response["product"]["price"]["price"])
```

Output:

```
1190.00
```